# Find lowest priced product in a category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I am looping through each sub-category and spitting out its name,url,image etc.

But I also want to show a "From £XX" for each sub category I show.

What is the best/cleanest method for doing this? My current code is below:

```
<?php
$currentCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('4');
$subCategories = $currentCat->getChildrenCategories();

foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategory )
{
    if($subCategory->getIsActive())
    {
        echo'<h3><a href="'.$subCategory->getUrl().'">'.$subCategory->getName().'</a></h3>';
          echo'<a href="'.$subCategory->getUrl().'">';
          echo'<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$subCategory->load($subCategory->getId())->getImage().'" alt="Budget Stove" />';
          echo'<div class="pl_prod_price">From <span>&pound;00.00</span></div>';
        echo'</a>';


    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code to get lowest price in subcategory

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategory->getId())
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC') //sets the order by price 
 ->getFirstItem(); 

echo $product->getFinalPrice();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I also want to answer to flag some issues.

The first issue with @Narayan's answer is that he has sorted by `price` and not by `finalprice` which is wrong.

The issue with @AmitBera's answer is that he has taken the product collection instead of the category collection, also `$collection->getFirst();` is wrong this should be `$collection->getFirstItem();`.

So here is your final answer

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($yourcategory_id)
 ->getProductCollection();
$collection
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents(); 
$collection->getSelect()->order("price_index.final_price ASC") // Sort Collection by ASC price
->limit(1) ;
$LowestPricedproduct= $collection->getFirstItem(); 
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency( $LowestPricedproduct->getFinalPrice() , true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

KiwisTasteGood,

First thing need to understand that Price is  **an attribute of product** and *not an attribute of catgory*.

If want to get lowest of price,then  you

- should call product collection of that category
- and get lowest price from that collection
- Sort that Collection by  final_price.

> $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
>   $collection->addMinimalPrice()->addFinalPrice()
>               ->addTaxPercents();  $collection->getSelect()     ->order("price_index.final_price  ASC") // Sort COllection by ASC
>   ->limit(1)     $LowestPricedproduct= $collection->getFirst(); $LowestPricedproduct->getFinalPrice();

Comment: "an attribute of product and not an attribute of product" so what is it then?

Comment: @AndreFerraz,thank for notice .. it  should be `an attribute of product and not an attribute of category"`. Typo mistake

Comment: Hi @AmitBera your answer help me, but there are few errors if you allow me then I would like to update your answer .